# Messages not sent to Azure Service Bus in integration tests

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, messaging

I want to perform integration tests which involve interaction with service bus. I have noticed that some messages are not sent, even though no exception gets thrown. I am using a free tier of ASB.

That's the service method responsible for sending the message:

```
    public class ServiceBusMessagingSender<T> : IMessagingSender<T> where T : IMessage
    {

    private readonly string _connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING_SENDER");
    private readonly ServiceBusSender _sender;
    private readonly IMessageSerializer<T> _messageSerializer;

    public ServiceBusMessagingSender(string queueName, IMessageSerializer<T> messageSerializer, string connectionString=null)
    {
        _messageSerializer = messageSerializer;
        _connectionString ??= connectionString;
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(_connectionString);
        this._sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
    }


    public void SendMessage(T message)
    {
        var serviceBusMessage = _messageSerializer.Serialize(message);
        _sender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

This method is then called in tests in NUnit suite:

```
    public class EndtoEndTests {

    private readonly ServiceBusMessagingSender<DataRequestDto> _messagingSender = new(RequestsQueue, new MessageSerializer<DataRequestDto>(), WriterConnectionString);


    [Test]
    public void GoodTypes()
    {
        //...
        
        //WHEN
        var request = new GoodTypesRequest()
        {
            RequestTimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            RequestType = RequestType.GoodTypes
        };

        _messagingSender.SendMessage(request );
        ///...
    }
}
```

I am using the following versions of packages for ASB:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.1.3" />
```

Comment: You can't share a tiny snippet and ask what went wrong. Please share the code if you meaningful help.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I have just shared more details

Comment: What is `ServiceBusMessagingSender`? How does it construct the sender? If you want to get help you gotta give the details. Don't piecemeal. It is likely an issue in your custom code but w/o seeing it is near impossible to suggest anything meaningful.

Comment: Okay, I have added the constructor part as well. Sorry for being chaotic a bit.

Comment: Thank you. What version of the ASB SDK you're using?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the versions of ASB SDK. My new observation is that more or less every second message isn't sent

Comment: Not sure why do you use both SDKs. Code wise (what's shared) it looks ok. Next, perhaps share a repro as a GitHub repo to see what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

You are calling a Async method inside a void so you are ending up in a race condition of if the send can complete before the function closes.
Change your function to a Task rather than void and the problem should go away.
You also might want to change `_sender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
to
`await _sender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);` for easier to read code.

Comment: .GetResult() will block call